# Outlook addin (AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface): how can ItemId be got for an existing event/meeting?

Tags: outlook-addin, office365-apps, outlook-web-addins

We've recently enabled AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface in our Outlook addin and noticed that it is always the Compose mode in which ItemId is not available, even when editing an existing appointment/meeting.

This sort of does not make sense for an existing appointment/meeting. Is there a way to get the ItemId?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The `itemId` property is not available in compose mode, which includes editing an existing appointment. If an item identifier is required, the `saveAsync` method can be used to save the item to the store, which will return the item identifier in the `AsyncResult.value` parameter in the callback function. ([source](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox.item?product=outlook#nullable-itemid-string))

**However**, `saveAsync` is currently not working as expected in Calendar. When calling `Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync` on a new Calendar item that has not been sent yet, the API will not save. We are aware of this issue and are looking into a solution to resolve this so that the API can be used as designed.

The API should behave as designed in Mail and on existing Calendar items. Note that for existing Calendar items, **calling `saveAsync` will send out an update to attendees** if the user or the add-in make changes in the compose form.

Comment: I care about an existing appointment/meeting in this case and using saveAsync is not the best approach. After all a user may be making some changes in the event itself that he/she may decide to discard them but opening our addin would save those and even send out notifications. Not good. Are there any plans to provide a way to get ItemId without saveAsync?

Comment: We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. It looks like the feature you want has been requested by others already. Please upvote the request here: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/17923540-we-need-support-for-itemid-in-compose-mode-for-app . Features on user-voice are also considered when we go through our planning process.